# Navigation from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I want to move from my `Activity` to `Fragment` without passing any variables, just simple move between `activity` to `fragment` .

im using this

```
 public void LihatMenu(View view) {
        MenuFragment menuFragment = new MenuFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerMain, menuFragment).commit();
    }
```

here the **activity_login_form.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".LoginForm"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/pal1c1"
    android:id="@+id/containerMain">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/LogoLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TvLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:text="@string/login"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TvNama"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nama"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EdNama"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TvMeja"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/meja"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"/>
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/SpinnerMeja"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TvLokasiMeja"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="1"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/BtnRefreshMeja"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="@string/refresh"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/pal1c3"
                android:onClick="RandomizeCode"/>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/BtnManualMeja"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="@string/edit_manual"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/pal1c3"
                android:onClick="EditSpinner"/>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TvKodeMeja"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/kode_meja"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EdKodeMeja"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:enabled="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnMasuk"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/pal1c3"
            android:onClick="masuk"
            android:text="@string/masuk"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnLihatMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/pal1c3"
            android:text="@string/lihat_menu"
            android:onClick="LihatMenu"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

on my `onclick` in my activity `Button`

but the view get stacked with `activity` and the `fragment` like this

[image]

how do i fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ohh I can just wrap the content of `ContainerMain` and make it `GONE`